# How can I add spacing or margin between rows in AG-Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

[image]

I am trying to create an AG-Grid table with Master/Detail functionality. While working on the styling, I encountered the issue mentioned above. I am also using the **autoHeight** property set to true.

Below is the code that I am using to style the rows.

```
getRowStyle: (params: any) => {
    const rowIndex = params.node.rowIndex;

    return {
        backgroundColor: rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? "#c9daf8" : "#6d9eeb",
        marginTop: rowIndex === 0 ? "0" : `${10 * rowIndex}px`,
        borderRadius: "8px",
        border: "none",
    };
},
```

This is causing some rows to be clipped, as shown in the screenshot. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?